# Any free alternatives of Cloudinary to host video with <video> tag in my website?

Tags: html, html5-video, host, cloudinary

do you know any free websites where I could load my video like this? Google Drive offers only an embed option. I don't have access to my web hosting server and I won't get it (corporate bureaucracy...).

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" poster="https://res.cloudinary.com/tadasp/image/upload/test.png"><source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tadasp/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.</video>
```

I need to host this video in my website just for 1-2 weeks. I thought Cloudinary free version would work but I'm started to reach a significant amount quota limit just by testing if the video works, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually work on Cloudinary's developer support team and would be happy to provide some help/insight here if needed.

Our free accounts get 25 credits on a rolling 30 day basis, and a credit represents 1GB of storage, or 1GB of bandwidth, or 1000 transformations. The initial upload of a video will count as just one transformation, and processing that video costs 2 transformations per second for SD video, or 4 transformations per second for HD video ([link](https://cloudinary.com/blog/understanding_cloudinary_s_transformation_quotas#content_upload)).

What we advise is using f_auto and q_auto in your video to optimize it for different browsers and devices. That way, when your site's visitors access the video, it consumes less bandwidth for both you and them, and it loads quicker too. Everyone wins :)

Taking [our dog video](https://demo-res.cloudinary.com/video/upload/dog.mp4) as an example, it's an 8.67 MB mp4 by default, but delivering it with f_auto & q_auto ([link](https://demo-res.cloudinary.com/video/upload/f_auto,q_auto/dog.mp4)), we serve a 470.86 KB webm on Chrome instead, saving a considerable amount of bandwidth.

You can read about f_auto and q_auto here in our guide on [video optimization](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_optimization), as well as some other tips to optimize your video. Generally speaking, a single video shouldn't cause you to go over a 25 credit quota, so I'd be interested in knowing a bit more about your video and/or use case, and will do my best to help. I tried looking up your cloud "tadasp", but it was either renamed or deleted because I'm not seeing it on our side.

If you need anything from Cloudinary Support, please feel free to reach out to us directly via our [support center](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new). We're a friendly bunch and always happy to help!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers! The original video is in my cloud. That one with 46+ MB. I could reduce the resolution a bit more and overall do optimization. But the thing is that the video will be on the company's homepage where we get thousands of users daily. That's why I though we will exceed that quota limits.

Comment: I looked at my Cloudinary report and I saw 901 MB Bandwidth and 221 Requests but the thing is that only I tested the video and refreshed the page a couple of times where the video is embedded. So basically quotas are for uploads and transformation of seconds? If I put my video on the website then it won't increase my quotas based on how many users will view the video served on the website? They won't go to the video URL hosted on Cloudinary.

Comment: The question is off topic for asking for software recommendations. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: @Tadas Point 3 of the first link, "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: @Tadas SO is not the place to ask for that as the rule clearly states.